# Choosing minimum length k of array for merge sort where use of insertion sort to sort the subarrays is more optimal than standard merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

This is a question from Introduction to Algorithms By Cormen. But this isn't a homework problem instead self-study.

There is an array of length `n`. Consider a modification to merge sort in which `n/k` sublists each of length `k` are sorted using insertion sort and then merged using merging mechanism, where k is a value to be determined.

The relationship between `n` and `k` isn't known. The length of array is `n`. `k` sublists of `n/k` means `n * (n/k)` equals `n` elements of the array. Hence `k` is simply a limit at which the splitting of array for use with merge-sort is stopped and instead insertion-sort is used because of its smaller constant factor.

I was able to do the mathematical proof that the modified algorithm works in `Θ(n*k + n*lg(n/k))` worst-case time. Now the book went on to say to

> find the largest value of `k` as a function of `n` for which this modified algorithm has the same running time as standard merge sort, in terms of Θ notation. How should we choose k in practice?

Now this got me thinking for a lot of time but I couldn't come up with anything. I tried to solve

`n*k + n*lg(n/k) = n*lg(n)` for a relationship. I thought that finding an equality for the 2 running times would give me the limit and greater can be checked using simple hit-and-trial.

I solved it like this

```
n k + n lg(n/k) = n  lg(n)

k + lg(n/k) = lg(n)

lg(2^k) + lg(n/k) = lg(n)

(2^k * n)/k = n

2^k = k
```

But it gave me `2 ^ k = k` which doesn't show any relationship. What is the relationship? I think I might have taken the wrong equation for finding the relationship.

I can implement the algorithm and I suppose adding an `if (length_Array < k)` statement in the `merge_sort` function [here(Github link of merge sort implementation)](https://github.com/anshbansal/general/blob/master/C/algorithms/Sorting/merge_sort.c) for calling insertion sort would be good enough. But how do I choose `k` in real life?

Comment: @JimMischel The relationship isn't known. The length of array is `n`. `k` sublists of `n/k` means `n * (n/k)` equals `n` elements of the array. I'll update the question with this detail.

Comment: I really shouldn't try to do elementary math in the morning. Comment deleted.

Comment: The answers given here are focused on the math for a theoretical processor with no cache. Since the 1990's, for an optimized bottom up merge sort that alternates the direction of merge with each merge pass (no copy back), if the number of passes would be odd, use `k`= 32, if the number of passes would be even, use 'k' = 64, leaving an even number of merge passes after doing the initial insertion sort pass, so that the sorted data ends up in the original array (rather than the temporary working array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a mathematical minimization problem, and to solve it, we need some basic calculus.

We need to find the value of `k` for which `d[n*k + n*lg(n/k)] / dk == 0`.

We should also check for the edge cases, which are `k == n`, and `k == 1`.

The candidate for the value of `k` that will give the minimal result for `n*k + n*lg(n/k)` is the minimum in the required range, and is thus the optimal value of `k`.

---

Attachment, solving the derivitives equation:

```
d[n*k + n*lg(n/k)] / dk = d[n*k + nlg(n) - nlg(k)] / dk
= n + 0 - n*1/k = n - n/k 
=>
n - n/k = 0 => n = n/k => 1/k = 1 => k = 1
```

Now, we have the candidates: k=n, k=1. For k=n we get `O(n^2)`, thus we conclude optimal `k` is `k == 1`.

---

Note that we found the derivitives on the function from the big Theta, and not on the exact complexity function that uses the needed constants. 

Doing this on the exact complexity function, with all the constants might yield a bit different end result - but the way to solve it is pretty much the same, only take derivitives from a different function.

Comment: Your mathematical proof is correct as far as I can tell but it doesn't make any sense. It is known that use of insertion sort for coarsening the leaves is better because of its small constant factor. `k == 1` suggests otherwise. Maybe my choice of equation is wrong in itself.

Comment: @AseemBansal Well, I was just thinking how to write something that addresses this issue. Note that we found the derivitives on the function from the big Theta, and not on the exact complexity function that uses the needed constants. Doing this on the exact complexity function, with all the constants might yield a bit different end result - but the way to solve it is pretty much the same, only take derivitives from a different function.

Comment: I just thought that minimizing the expression `n*k + n*lg(n/k)` just finds the minimum of the modified algorithm w.r.t. `k`. It won't find for which value it is lesser than `n lg(n)`. Correct or wrong?

Comment: @AseemBansal It will find the minimal value of `k`, and if for this value, the result of `n*k + n*lg(n/k)` is smaller then `nlg(n)` - it gives you one such value. Otherwise - such value does not exist (which is the case in here..)

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. The book says that `It makes sense to coarsen the leaves of the recursion by using insertion sort within merge sort when subproblems become sufficiently small.` So there are solutions and one of the writers (a professor at MIT) stated himself in [first of these video lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/) that this is practically better. So there is a solution for this. Maybe I started the maths at wrong place leading to this wrong solution.

Comment: @AseemBansal the practical solution is better if you use the real complexity function (including the constants ignored in big Theta) and compare it to the real complexity function of merge sort.

Comment: That makes sense. You left answering the last paragraph. How to choose `k` in real life?

Comment: In real life you should probably make a series of experiments, and find out the best value of `k` you empirically recived from these experiments. You will have to make sure the answer is statistically significant (and if it is not, you will need more experiments until it is). Empirical research is a huge field, that is not covered in Cormen's book at all, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

maybe `k` should be `lg(n)`

`theta(nk + nlog(n/k))` have two terms, we have the assumption that `k>=1`, so the second term is less than `nlog(n)`.

only when `k=lg(n)`, the whole result is `theta(nlog(n))`