# Modified version of merge sort which uses insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

After I have divided an array using merge sort,till the array has length k,I'm supposed to use insertion sort on the k length array and then continue with merging. What should be the optimal value of k?

Also, I found these questions similar to mine but didn't find a definite answer
[Choosing minimum length k of array for merge sort where use of insertion sort to sort the subarrays is more optimal than standard merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104370/choosing-minimum-length-k-of-array-for-merge-sort-where-use-of-insertion-sort-to)
[Modification to merge sort to implement merge sort with insertion sort Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533057/modification-to-merge-sort-to-implement-merge-sort-with-insertion-sort-java)

Comment: Note that the linked to question uses bottom up merge sort, and starts off by treating an array of size n as n/k sub-arrays of size k, as opposed to a top down recursive dividing of an array until sub-array size <= k. A common value for k is 32, but I don't know if it's optimal.

Comment: Has my answer become wrong? ;=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This I feel was a more proper answer for my question http://atekihcan.github.io/CLRS/P02-01/, quoting it here,

For the modified algorithm to have the same asymptotic running time as standard merge sort,

```
Θ(nk+nlg(n/k))=Θ(nk+nlgn−nlgk)
```

must be same as

```
Θ(nlgn).
```

To satisfy this condition, k cannot grow faster than lg⁡n asymptotically (if k grows faster than lg⁡n, because of the nk term, the algorithm will run at worse asymptotic time than Θ(nlgn). But just this argument is not enough as we have to check for

```
k=Θ(lgn),
```

the requirement holds or not.

If we assume,

```
k=Θ(lgn),

Θ(nk+nlg(n/k))=Θ(nk+nlgn−nlgk)=Θ(nlgn+nlgn−nlg(lgn))=Θ(2nlgn−nlg(lgn))†=Θ(nlgn)
```

†lg(lgn) is very small compared to lgn for sufficiently larger values of n.

Answer (score 0):

Just measure.

The best threshold value depends on your programming language, data type, daata set value distribution, computer hardware, mergesort and insertion sort implementation details and so on.

Usually this value is in range 10-200, and the gain for the best value is not very significant.